# set up magento 2 change all to https, now only html - no css js and I can access admin as login fails

Tags: magento2, admin, https

I've set up magento 2 and changed all urls to https, now only html shows on the site - no css js and I now can't access admin as login fails.

I've checked out docs, forum, stack exchange and tried changing in mysql via phpmyadmin to no avail.

Surely this is something that most noobs do as we all want to set to secure right?
So why is it too easy to do this and why are there no warnings on the docs?

Maybe I just need to completely reinstall Magento 2 again as it's taken me hours to try to figure it out.
Any help is much appreciated.